# Eu consigo salvar em uma variável os dados que vem de um laço de repetição python?

Tags: python, lógica, while

Eu queria saber se eu consigo pegar o valor que o whille achou na interação e colocar em uma variável para eu usar depois que o laço de repetição finalizar.

```
contador = 0

while (contador < 3):

time_casa = site.find_all('div', attrs={'.nomeclass'})[0].text

contador   = contador + 1
```

tipo, eu queria salvar em uma variável o nome de cada time que o whille encontra.

Comment: Python é sensível ao recuo, esse fragmento deverá gerar um erro de sintaxe na linha `while (contador < 3):`. Não duplique as perguntas, esse fragmento é derivado [daqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/539787/criar-arquivo-json-a-partir-de-la%c3%a7o-de-repeti%c3%a7%c3%a3o-whille) e o código possui o mesmo problema desse fragmento, não está endentado adequadamente. [`find_all()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-the-tree) retorna uma lista contendo os elementos buscados, então itere pela lista obtida com  `find_all()` colhendo os dados de cada elemento.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Tem como fazer desse jeito

```
Nomes = []                                           
Contador = int(input("Quantas vezes você quer rodar o código? "))
while (Contador > 0):
    Pergunta = input("Qual é o seu nome? ")
    Nomes.append(Pergunta)
    Contador -= 1
print(Nomes)
```

Nesse caso os nomes vão ficar salvos na lista "Nome".

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).